# What to store more in a graph database, properties in node or relationship?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have been playing around with graph database neo4j for a while. I was trying a read cypher on complete database using neo4j community edition. It is taking quite a while to return the results.
The read result had lot of redundant data. The database that I have created has more node properties rather than relationships.

This brought me to a situation which I am not sure of. 
Should I store more properties within nodes or create relationships out of them for faster cypher results.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the data in your graph, otherwise there's no way we can provide much to you that will be meaningful. In general, however, it's a good idea to consider the important "things" in your graph, and model those as nodes under a certain label, then connect those nodes with relationships. You'll also want to add constraints and indexes as necessary depending on where your matches begin. The more you tell us about your model, the more room we have to suggest approaches and improvements.

Comment: This is far too broad a question for StackOverflow, and will only get you discussion and opinions. Plus (as @InverseFalcon points out), we don't even know what your current model looks like, since you've included no details at all. Please edit your question accordingly, before it ends up getting closed as 'too broad' or 'unclear.'